# Ruby match String variable in regular expression

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string variable:

```
e = 'mystring'
```

How can I match the string `'abcd mystring abcd'`?

I have tried

```
'abcd mystring abcd' =~ /e/
'abcd mystring abcd' =~ /(e)/
'abcd mystring abcd' =~ /#{e}/
```

But none of them generate a match.

---

I found the problem, actually I was using

```
'abcd mystring abcd' =~ /(.*)#{e}(.*)/
```

which didn't have a match, therefore I thought `/#{e}/` wouldn't give a match as well.

---

I thought the return value 0 means a match failure... It turns out only the nil means a failure.

Comment: Cannot be reproduced. `'abcd mystring abcd' =~ /#{e}/` does have a match.

Comment: Make sure to regex-quote the string as appropriate (while this example should work, it might not in your "real code")

Comment: Your update also works - it returns `0` - which means that the string matches from its start...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create a regex from a string, you can use the [`new()` constructor](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#method-c-new):

```
'abcd mystring abcd' =~ Regexp.new(e)
```

Comment: That is the preferred way, but the OP doesn't have to. The OP's last example should work as well.

Comment: @sawa: I see. Can you point me to documentation that explains that `#{}` syntax? I'm not a Ruby person, and the Ruby docs are hard to search for something like this.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Regular expression literals use the same interpolation as double-quoted string literals.

Comment: Thanks! I also found an answer in the Regexp docs: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Regexp%23match+method

Answer (score 0):

You also match the required string like

e = 'mystring'

'abcd mystring abcd'.match(/#{e}/)

if it matched then return MatchData object else return nil.